# ImageView conditionals alternatives (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am a basic beginner at android studio and I am developing a weather app. I want to put conditionals for icon images to weather condition.

For example:

```
sun = sun image 
rain = rain image
snow = snow image
```

I understand a switch case might be useful:

```
        switch (id) {
        case "Raining":
            icon = "rainIcon";
            break;
        case "Snowing":
            icon = "snowIcon";
            break;
        case "Drizzling":
            icon = "drizzlingIcon";
            break;
        case "Foggy":
            icon = "fogIcon";
            break;
        case "Thunderstorm":
            icon = "thunderIcon;";
            break;
        case "Sunny":
            icon = "sunIcon";
            break;
    }
```

However, I am confused how to implement it into my code as I am retrieving my data from my AsyncTask and need to implement the image change in that class but there is no proper method to change my ImageView variable there.

I understand there are ways to implement this on the onCreateView method but this is the way my code is implemented right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to create an enum of type Weathers.

```
public enum Weathers {

   RAINING(R.drawable.ic_raining),
   SNOWING(R.drawable.ic_snowing);

   private int iconResId;

   private Weathers(int iconResId) {
      this.iconResId = iconResId;
   }
   public int getIconResId() {
      return iconResId;
   }
}
```

This might lessen the conditionals (The switch case above). To display into imageview, get an instance of the Weather instance by using `Weathers.valuesOf(String)` where `String` is upper-cased.

```
Weathers snowing = Weathers.valueOf("Snowing".toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH));
imageViewIcon.setImageResource(snowing.getIconResId());
```

Comment: I appreciate your help alot @Gero.